# date object prefixing with # vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am writing sample code for Date conversion using VB.net.
Problem i am facing that it is prefixing and suffixing with hash(#) symbol.
ex : #2010-12-12#.

How to remove # symbol so that i can only date.

Comment: Where is this prefixing happening, exactly? On the console, in the debugger, ...?

Comment: Posting the code would help, too. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: In the debugger arrTxLifeReq(0).TransExeDate = Convert.ToDateTime(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your comment, it sounds like this is *actually* probably just an issue of displaying a `DateTime` in the debugger. It showing you the `DateTime` literal form that you could use in VB. This is a bit like C# developers who are concerned about their strings having double backslashes in, when actually that's just the debugger showing escaping.

The `DateTime` itself doesn't really contain the hashes, and none of the normal format strings will produce hashes either. If you want to see it without the hashes, add a watch for

```
arrTxLifeReq(0).TransExeDate.ToString()
```

Does the code which is part of your real program have any problems? If so, please post details of *those* problems rather than just what the debugger is showing.

Comment: Actually , i need to send date to xml . when i am doing that in vb.net value is not showing up. In the receiving end , TransExeDate is coming as empty.

Comment: @Madhu: So where is 2010-12-12 coming from then? You should edit your question to give a lot more details of what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: In xml , the datatype for <TransExeDate> is Date. so when i am assigning arrTxLifeReq(0).TransExeDate =  System.DateTime.Now() in vb.net , the value is not coming in actual xml in the receving end

Comment: @Madhu: Well, we'll need an awful lot more information about the code involved. You should either edit your question heavily (don't just add comments here) or start a new question instead.

Comment: Thanks jon , i solved it by adding arrTxLifeReq(0).TransExeDateSpecified = True .

Answer (score 0):

Just replace # with ''

for example

```
string dt = "#2010-12-12#";

dt = dt.Replace ("#","");
```