# Formatting date removes zeroes

Tags: vb.net, winforms, date, format

I'm looking for a way to keep the zeroes in single digit months and days however the current way I'm doing it now isn't working.  I"m looking for some insight as to what may have happened and if I"m not formatting correctly.

Currently I'm looking just to format the date into a specific format, here's my code:

```
dateFormat = Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

however the value of this isn't the 02/13/2013 value I was expecting it's #2/13/2013# removing all leading zeroes.  What is going on here and why is it giving the # and removing all leading zeroes?

Comment: Please show the rest of your code that is involved

Comment: This is all that is used to format the date.  Other than declaring the variable Dim dateFormat As DateTime

Comment: There must and an error elsewhere. The formats `MM` and `dd` always yield a two digit number!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant question is: Of what type is `dateFormat`? If it is a `Date` (or `DateTime`) then the formatted string will be converted back to a `Date` and the formatting will be lost. The formatting only works if you assign the result of the formatting to a `String`. The `Date` type does not store any formatting. Formatting in general only applies to strings.

```
Dim dateFormat As String
dateFormat = Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

**Note**: If you have `Option Strict Off` then VB automatically attempts to convert non-matching types. In your code the formatted string will automatically be converted to `Date` if `dateFormat` is of `Date` type. Therefore `Option Strict Off` is dangerous, since it hides potential programming errors. I strongly encourage you to use `Option Strict On`. You can do that either per source file or in the project properties under `Compile > Option Strict`.

When doing so, you will lose some automatic conversions and you will have to specify those conversions explicitly but you will increase the security of your code.

You can even set this option as default for new projects in menu `Tools > Options`, then navigate to `Projects and Solutions > VB Defaults`. (At least in VS 2008). I always have:

```
    Option Explicit On
    Option Strict On
    Option Compare Binary
    Option Infer On
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare dateFormat as string :

```
Dim dateFormat as string = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

As for the "hashes". [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4274526/799558) explains it.

> The DateTime itself doesn't really contain the hashes, and none of the
>   normal format strings will produce hashes either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the proper way of VB.NET [date formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59bz1f0h%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
    Dim DateFormat As DateTime = Now
    Console.WriteLine(Format(DateFormat, "Short Date"))
```

Comment: This is the "old school way" not "proper way" ;-)

Comment: but fit for the solution, sometimes is more readable than the new one `:D`